# NodeJS Gzip unzipping

Tags: node.js, gzip

I am fairly new to NodeJS. Today I created a zipper/unzipper test:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var zlib = require('zlib');

var inputFile = "files/input.txt";
var outputFile = "files/input2.txt";

function info(path) {
    fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log("\n>>>>File: " + path +"\n\tsize: "+ stats.size);
    })
}

// zip
fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
    .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('files/compressed.gz'));

console.log("File Compressed.");
info(inputFile);

// unzip
fs.createReadStream('files/compressed.gz')
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputFile));

console.log("File Decompressed.");
info(outputFile);
```

The output (input2.txt) is successfully created, however I'm getting a 0 byte sized unzipped file. I tried to run it from cmd and from WebStorm as well.